# IIS web site with host name can't be accessed by IP address

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mobile, iis-7, asp.net-web-api

I have mvc 4 web api project set up on IIS giving host name as my computer name. When I call it by mycoumputername:portno, I can access my web api. But when I call it by myIPaddress:portno, I couldn't access it. But when I create new Site without giving host name as computer name, default as localhost, it can be access by IPaddress:portno. I can't find the reason. Anyway, I need to define hostname as my computer name to access from remote computers by www.mycomputername.com and also need to use IPAddress:portno for accessing from mobile. 
Please help me, anyone. Thank you and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the host name setting.

When you set a host name in IIS site binding you explicitly requires all requests to this site to contain the desired host header (read HTTP protocol for details).

When your browser accesses the site using the IP address, the requests won't contain the header to match your IIS side setting.

That's simply by design.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a new binding in IIS for the domain without a host name and with the port number.